# Vue.js dynamic components and lists

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have a basic task list component and a task item component.

```
 <template>
      <task v-for="(task, index) in tasks" :is="task" >{{ task.name }}</task>
 </template>
```

I have an edit button on the task like so:

```
<template>  
    <slot></slot>
    <button v-on:click="$emit('edit')">Edit</button>    
</template>
```

Is there an easy way to change the specific task component to task-edit when edit is clicked?

The HTML for the page is just:

```
<task-list></task-list>
```

Update: [Here is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rdjjpc7a/2217/).

Comment: If you want to dynamically change the rendered component you can use dynamic components. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

Comment: yes, hence the ```:is```. The main question is, does the dynamic component need to affect the entire list, or can I choose a component for only one list item?

Comment: Gotcha. Have a working fiddle/codepen?

Comment: I'll whip one up, it's going to be a pain because all my components are getting compiled so I have to strip them apart for fiddle.

Comment: Off hand though, `task` could have a `task.mode` or something that you could toggle with your button click, and then set `:is="task.mode"`

Comment: Something like http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/EWwQrr

Comment: Yes kind of but it looks like that example is applying the component to all list items, vs just one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a mode that represents the component you want to use and set `:is="task.mode"`.

```
<div id="app">
  <list></list>
</div>

<template id="list-template">
  <div>
    <component v-for='task in tasks' 
               :is='task.mode' 
               :task='task'
               @edit="edit"
               @save="save">
    </component>
  </div>
</template>

<template id="task-template">
  <div>
    <h1>{{task.text}}</h1>
    <button @click="$emit('edit', task)">Edit</button>
   </div>
</template>

<template id="task-edit-template">
  <div>
    <input type="text" :value="task.text">
    <button @click="$emit('save', task)">Save</button>
   </div>
</template>
```

Code

```
Vue.component("list",{
  template:"#list-template",
  data(){
    return {
      tasks:[{text: "task1", mode:"task"}, {text: "task1", mode:"task"}]
    }
  },
  methods:{
    edit(task){
      task.mode = "task-edit"
    },
    save(task){
      task.mode = "task"
    }
  }
})

Vue.component("task", {
  props:["task"],
  template:"#task-template",
})

Vue.component("task-edit",{
  props:["task"],
  template:"#task-edit-template"
})

new Vue({
  el:"#app"
})
```

[Working example](http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/EWwQrr?editors=1010). Note: doesn't actually save edits.